# Непроизносимые согласные в словах, начинающихся на Е, Щ, Э, Ю

Tags: орфография, согласные

Помогите найти слова с непроизносимыми согласными в слове, которые начинаются на Е, Щ, Э, Ю. Если есть такие вообще?

Comment: @Евгения1981, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Я**в**ственный

Иногда к этой орфограмме относят экскаватор, где К плохо произносится
яства и юрисконсульт - сомнительный согласный, потому что можно ошибиться и услышать якобы непроизносимый, написать явства и юристконсульт

Answer (score 1):

"...есть такие вообще?"

Есть. Поищите среди этих:

*единовла(стн)ый,
ёмко(стн)ый,
щетиноли(стн)ый,
эберти(стск)ий,
эвере(стск)ий (от Эверест),
эволюциони(стск)ий,
эгофутури(стск)ий,
экзистенциали(стск)ий,
эксгибициони(стск)ий,
экспансиони(стск)ий,
экспрессиони(стск)ий,
экстреми(стск)ий,
эмотиви(стск)ий,
евроцентри(стск)ий,
юниони(стск)ий,
ютла(ндц)ы,
ютла(ндск)ий,
эмигра(нтск)ий,
эспера(нтск)ий.*